# inputStream.read() read wrong Boolean value

Tags: java, sockets, io, inputstream, bytebuffer

Sever code

```
                if(success){
                    out.write("true".getBytes().length);
                    out.write("true".getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                }
                else{
                    out.write("false".getBytes().length);
                    out.write("false".getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                }
```

Client Code

```
        int size = inputStream.read();
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        inputStream.read(buf);
        ns = new String(buf);
        Boolean.valueOf(ns);
```

Although the sever send the result client read it wrong. What is the problem in here? how can i solve it. As example sever send value true but client receive it as false

Comment: "read it wrong" doesn't give us *any* information. There are all kinds of things wrong here to be honest, such as using the platform-default encoding, assuming that all the strings will be < 256 bytes, encoding the data twice, assuming that a single call to `read(byte[])` will read all the data etc. Consider using `DataOutputStream` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to step thread what you are doing exactly.  Obviously the simplest way to sent a boolean is as a single byte like this.

```
out.write(success ? 1 : 0);
```

and to read this you would do

```
boolean success = in.read() != 0;
```

However, if you need to send a string, I would check what string you are reading and what the correct length is, because there is any number of reasons a binary protocol can fail, e.g. because the previous thing you read/wrote was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Server and Client are probably using different charsets.

Use an explicit one (and the same) in both sides.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException
```

and

```
public String(byte[] bytes,
          String charsetName)
   throws UnsupportedEncodingException
```